# Backbone modularized pattern with xhr on fetch

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to use alter the xhr object on an ajax request. I'm doing this on a fetch call for a collection. But when I alter the xhr I get no data. The purpose of this is to show the loaders percentage but the xhr isn't even working when I return the new xhr object. I did checkout the xhr that is returned and the url points to /admin/categories

```
    require(['views/categories', 'models/categories', 'helpers/helper'], function(CategoriesView, model, helper) {

    var categories = new model.CategoriesCollection;

    categories.fetch({ url: "/admin/categories/getcategories", xhr: helper.xhr('#main-loader') }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

and here is my helper file

```
define(['helpers/helper', 'require'], function(Helper, require) {

    'use strict';

    var $ = require('jquery');
    var Backbone = require('backbone');

    var xhr = function(loaderId) {

        var _xhr = Backbone.$.ajaxSettings.xhr();        

        _xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(e){      

            if (e.lengthComputable) {

                console.log(e);
            }
        }, false);
        return _xhr;
    }

    return  {    
        xhr: xhr        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to pass options to the `xhr` object (`XMLHttpRequest` object) is to use the `xhrFields` option of the [jQuery ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Since [Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) uses `jQuery.ajax` by default in the background, any options passed to a Backbone syncing function is then passed as the `ajax` options.

## Simple one-off solution

The simplest example of checking progress:

```
myCollection.fetch({
    url: root + '/photos/',
    xhrFields: {
        onprogress: function() {
            console.log("options onprogress");
        }
    }
});
```

## Permanent solution

But a more convinient way would be to override the global `Backbone.sync` function to add our own `progress` callback option and a custom `progress` event.

### Overriding `Backbone.sync`

*Warning: don't override Backbone core if you're writing a library or code that will be shared.*

```
Backbone.sync = (function(syncFn) {
    return function(method, model, options) {
        options = options || {};
        var context = options.context,
            progress = options.progress,
            xhrFields = options.xhrFields || {},
            onprogress = xhrFields.onprogress;

        xhrFields.onprogress = function(e) {
            var params = [model, e.loaded, _.extend({}, options, { event: e })];
            if (progress) progress.apply(context, params)
            if (onprogress) onprogress.apply(this, arguments);
            model.trigger(['progress'].concat(params));
        };

        options.xhrFields = xhrFields;

        return syncFn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(Backbone.sync);
```

### How to use

It's really straight-forward to use:

```
var myCollection = new Backbone.Collection(),
    root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
```

It provides a custom `progress` event.

```
myCollection.listenTo(myCollection, 'progess', function(collection, value, options) {
    console.log("collection progress event");
});
```

It also provides a custom `progress` callback that can be passed to any Backbone functions that calls `Backbone.sync` in the background, like `fetch`, `save`, `destroy`. Also, passing `xhrFields` still works as expected.

```
myCollection.fetch({
    url: root + '/photos/',
    success: function() {
        console.log(myCollection.models);
    },
    // custom options callback
    progress: function(collection, value, options) {
        console.log("collection onprogress callback");
    },
    // this still works
    xhrFields: {
        onprogress: function() {
            console.log("options onprogress");
        }
    }

});
```

You receive the collection or model, the loaded data count, and the `options` object, which contains all the options of the sync, in addition to the native progress event (`options.event`).

Note that it's not that useful as the total doesn't always work. As an example, in Chrome the total is always zero, but in firefox, the total is correct. You should check the `lengthComputable` property.